# React: How to send specific data to a specific instance of a component created with .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am creating multiple instances of a child component from a parent component like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        {this.state.accounts.map(account => 
            <EachAccount key={account.id} curAccountData={account} /> 
        )}
    )
}
```

When the EachAccount components are created they are each given unique data which works fine and each State of EachAccount component is unique.

But I want to pass data to just one of these instances AFTER they have already been created.

I tried passing data to the EachAccount component after it had already been created but unfortunately every instance got the data and therefore the state of every one of the instances got updated.

Anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: How about adding this data in account and in loop, if any account has `data` you pass it as a prop

Comment: For that you need a global store like Redux so you can use same state for multiple components.

Comment: Are you sure that the data should live in the child component state? It looks like what you really need is to keep your data in parent state and pass function references and value as props to child component to modify parent state / show data rather than passing data to child component state after the component is created.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN The data I am trying to pass is actually their updated state, I want to click a button on the parent component and have only a specific child's state get updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I found is to send the data with the ID of the child that you would like to update as a prop to every instance, and then inside of the child make a conditional that will only update the state if the current child ID and the send data ID match.

Something like this would be in the EachAccount component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     if(nextProps.updateBalanceFromId === this.state.curAccountData.id){
         this.getBalances(nextProps.updateBalanceFromId)
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
    renderAccounts(){
      return this.state.accounts.map(account => {
         if(certainCondition){
           // return Each Account with extra data
         }

         return (
           <EachAccount key={account.id} curAccountData={account} />

      })
    }

    render(){
     return (
       {this.renderAccounts()}
     )
    }

}
```